# How do i color each cell based on condition in Datatables.js after rendering the table from json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, spotfire, datatables-1.10

```
var dataset = [];
var columns = sfdata.columns

sfdata.data.forEach(function (item,index) {
    var n2 = item.items
    dataset.push(n2)
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataset,
        columns: [
            { title: "index" },
            { title: "Name" }

        ]
    });
});
```

So I've made the default table in spotfire, now the question is how do i color values in a column based on conditions like (if data[2] > 10 then background-color be 'red'). Am i instantiating it wrong; how do i get it to work?

Comment: Can you create snippet with sample data by editing your question?

Comment: In the column definition, you could add `class` attribute or you could use the `rowDrawCallback` to achieve the same

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to add `createdRow` to the `DataTable()` invocation?

```
$("#example").DataTable({
  "data": dataset,
  "columns": [
    { "title": "index" },
    { "title": "Name" }
  ],
  "createdRow": (row, data, dataIndex) => {
    if(data[2] >  10)
    {
      $(row).addClass("redClass");
    }
  }
});
```

And in CSS:

```
.redClass
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

This comes directly from the [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36595/change-the-row-color-based-on-column-data).

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
     "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets":3,
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
         var highlight="";
         if(data==5407 || data == 1314)highlight="link"; // Put your conditions here
          return '<span class="'+highlight+'"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+data+'</span>';
        }
  } ],
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    $(".link").parent().addClass("link");
  }
   });  
  
});
```

```css
.link{
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/fbd569b8768155c7a9a62568e66a64115887d7d0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h3>jQuery DataTables - ROWSPAN in table body TBODY</h3>

<hr><br>
    
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Use `column.render` to achieve this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks . But i'm not able to pull data with the "Ajax" attribute.

Comment: Use dataset instead, i fetched data from remote location.

Comment: One more thing , do you know how do i add icons inside a cell. i tried using bootstrap css but its not working, if you have anything working can you pass me on the CDN and how did you do it?

Comment: @ShricharanArumugam use font awesome

Comment: @ShricharanArumugam  I updated answer with icon please check

Answer (score 2):

if you want to style a specific cell based on a column you have to use columnDefs with render option as a callback with a target which refers to the column you want to control the cells in (you can take look [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) also).

so the code should look like that:

```
  var dataSet = [
["Tiger Nixon", 1, "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
["Garrett Winters", 12, "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
["Ashton Cox", 4, "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
["Cedric Kelly", 5, "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
["Airi Satou", 23, "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
["Brielle Williamson", 54, "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
["Herrod Chandler", 2, "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"]
  ];

var columnDefs = [{
   title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

var myTable;

myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
   data: dataSet,
   columns: columnDefs,
   columnDefs: [{
     targets: 1, // this means controlling cells in column 1
     render: function(data, type, row, meta) { 
       if (data > 10) { // here is your condition
         return '<div class="red-color">' + data + '</div>';
       } else {
         return data;
       }
     }
   }]
 });
```

and here is a working [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad408/6p17bw23/6/)

Comment: how do i give conditions for multiple columns?

Comment: columnDefs takes an array of objects, you can consider each object represent a column, you just have to change the target number.
i have updated the snippet you can take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammad408/6p17bw23/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46691/columndefs-targets-by-class-name-not-working-when-columns-defined-in-js) to achieve what you want.

`targets` is the the column number you want to filter out and render is the event which will be triggered when that column is going to be rendered. So, you have the data you want, based on the data you can filter out the result and apply the `background-color`.

Here is the demo.

```js
var dataSet = [{
  index: 1,
  name: "test"
}, {
  index: 2,
  name: "test2"
}, {
  index: 3,
  name: "test3"
}];


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
        data: "index"
      },
      {
        data: "name"
      }
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
     targets : [0],
      render: function(data, type, row) {
      
        if(row.index>2){
          return "<div style='background-color:red'>"+data+"<div>";
        }
        return data;
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```